# A database in a Java executable

Tags: java

So, to summarize, I'm developing a program for a friend to help her run her business, allowing her to track her clients, who is paid up to date, who owes her money, etc.  It also keeps a database of her menu, to allow her to add new clients to the database easily, by autofilling information based on the service chosen from the menu.

Here's my question: Currently I am developing this on my own computer on Eclipse, planning on making an executable that I can give to her after the program is developed.  I had originally planned on using MySQL to create and retrieve information from the database, but from looking into it, it appears she would need to install MySQL herself and that I may need to reconfigure things in the code once it's on her computer.  Id like to create a database in a way that wouldn't require her to install anything extra on her end.  Is there a way to use SQL where she won't have to install another program to use it, or do I need to find another way to store her customer information (like in txt files or something)?

I saw something called h2, but looking at it, it seemed to require an installation to use, so I assume writing to the database would also require an installation, so she would need to install that too.  If I'm wrong, and h2 would allow me to develop a database where she wouldn't need to install anything on her end, that would work, I just would like someone to confirm that before I put hours into it to find out it doesn't work.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You might take a look into SQLite. It is basically a simplistic database stored in a single file

Comment: If this is for her business, then I wouldn't embed the database in the application. The database should be on a real server (like DigitalOcean, AWS, or similar) that does backup snapshots. Otherwise, if she damages her computer or it gets stolen, all data is lost.

Answer (score 1):

H2 and HSQLDB can both be embedded into the application without need for any additional install.

Of the two, I'd suggest H2 is more reliable.  Please note that default config is for transient data, i.e. data is kept only in memory and lost if the application shuts down.  I believe this can be configured to be persistent on the file system, but does require some config.

While H2 *can* be installed, it does not *need* a separate install.  If you're using a dependency mgmt tool like maven or gradle (and I recommend using one), you can simply add it as a dependency and it will be bundled with your artefact.

Comment: I can confirm that I have used many times H2 that way in tests to avoid using a full blown database.

Comment: If H2 is default only used for transient data, wouldn't HSQLDB be better then?  As I said in the original question, this would keep track of her clients, including who has paid and still owes her money, as well as her menu.  As such, the database would need to survive the program being shut down.

Comment: They both have that behaviour available via config.  Obviously transient data does not work for your usecase, so you'll need to ensure you configure persistence.  I just have found H2 to be generally more sophisticated/reliable.